# Php image and description uploading without mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to write sort of image upload script that would upload file and write a line for each uploaded image with description and everything. 
Right now if i use $i++ function it will always write $i=0, because there is no foreach tag and I don't really know if its possible to use foreach tag for this kind of script without database etc..

```
if ($_FILES[image][size] > 0) {
    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES[image][name]));
    if (strtolower($ext) == 'jpg' || strtolower($ext) == 'png' || strtolower($ext) == 'bmp') {
        $tmp     = $_FILES[image][tmp_name];
        $new     = "$folder/" . time() . "_" . base64_encode($_POST[filename]) . "_" . base64_encode($_FILES[image][name]) . ".$ext";
        $p_name  = $_POST[project_name];
        $p_about = $_POST[project_about];
        file_put_contents('images.txt', $new . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $new);
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    die;
 }
```

$p_name and $p_about is not used yet. 
What I want is to write each line an unique ID than the project name , than about project and than the image link in order to delete specific rows when you delete an image by function which I will have to write.

Comment: `foreach($_FILES[image] as $image_file)`

Comment: this question isn't very clear. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. take out all the stuff about functions that don't relate to this (delete rows?) and try and explain it a little better

Comment: Basically what i want is an uploader that will not only upload but will also write description to uploaded item. Than via call function i will display all the uploaded items in to a list with images and descripton, also it will have a delete option. What i want is to make it have records for each item so when i get to display and delete options i will have an ability to erase the records for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use json for something like this.

```
<?php
$storage_file = './path/to/storage.json';
touch($storage_file);
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$storage = json_decode($storage,true);
$storage = empty($storage) ? array() : $storage;

$new_record = array();
$new_record['p_name'] = $_POST[project_name];
$new_record['p_about'] = $_POST[project_about];
$new_record['file'] = $new;

$new_id = count($storage);
$storage[] = $new_record;

file_put_contents($storage_file,json_encode($storage));

echo 'New ID: '.$new_id;
?>
```

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by.. 
tried to add file append but it doesnt help, it just doesnt write new lines.

Comment: Oh sorry it writes everything in a single line , but still i get that error that annoys me =/.

Comment: Just remove the `echo 'New ID: '.$new_id;`

Comment: great it works now, thanks , haha now I'll have to search tutorials on how to display items from json file and sort them , plus delete option

Comment: Just repeat the process up to `$storage = empty($storage) ? array() : $storage;` then use `print_r($storage)` to display them on the screen. You could also change `$storage[] = $new_record;` to something like `$uid = uniqid(); $storage[$uid] = $new_record;` to generate a unique ID for each entry. `unset($storage[$uid])` would then delete the entry.

Comment: Still having some problems, the 1st problem that the second entire copies the first one and adds a new one to it example:
`{"548aee0b0a00f":{"p_name":"ex","p_about":null,"file":"images\/1.png"}}{"548aee0b0a00f":{"p_name":"ex","p_about":null,"file":"images\/1.png"},"573aee4b0a1f":{"p_name":"ex","p_about":null,"file":"images\/2.png"}}`
after that it creates normally each entire without copying the one that was befre , its an issue only for the 1st entire.

Now the problem with print_r($storage) , it reads only if i have only 1 entire , if i have more it just outputs Array()